# How do I create multiple objects with data from JSON using gson (Java)?

Tags: java, json, gson

So I have some JSON I want to parse into an array list of objects (a). a would hold the href link and text, price, and image link.

This is the JSON:

```
{  
   "url":"http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_sacat=0&LH_ItemCondition=3000&_nkw=macbook%20pro%2015%202012&rt=nc&LH_BIN=1&_trksid=p2045573.m1684",
   "result":{  
      "extractorData":{  
         "url":"http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_sacat=0&LH_ItemCondition=3000&_nkw=macbook%20pro%2015%202012&rt=nc&LH_BIN=1&_trksid=p2045573.m1684",
         "resourceId":"73c12187d3f6d12410d3e7490cb91d9a",
         "data":[  
            {  
               "group":[                      
                  {  
                     "Img image":[  
                        {  
                           "src":"http://thumbs.ebaystatic.com/images/g/xMYAAOSwE7RXF7p5/s-l225.jpg",
                           "href":"http://www.ebay.com/itm/15-Apple-MacBook-Pro-RETINA-2-3GHz-Core-i7-8GB-256GB-Flash-MC975LL-A-Warranty-/121983722648?hash=item1c66cbe498:g:xMYAAOSwE7RXF7p5"
                        }
                     ],
                     "Vip link":[  
                        {  
                           "text":"New listing 15\" Apple MacBook Pro RETINA -2.3GHz Core i7-8GB-256GB Flash-MC975LL/A+Warranty",
                           "href":"http://www.ebay.com/itm/15-Apple-MacBook-Pro-RETINA-2-3GHz-Core-i7-8GB-256GB-Flash-MC975LL-A-Warranty-/121983722648?hash=item1c66cbe498:g:xMYAAOSwE7RXF7p5"
                        }
                     ],
                     "Bold price":[  
                        {  
                           "text":"$989.00"
                        },
                        {  
                           "text":"$989.00"
                        }
                     ],
                     "Lvformat value":[  
                        {  
                           "text":"Buy It Now"
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {  
                     "Img image":[  
                        {  
                           "src":"http://ir.ebaystatic.com/pictures/aw/pics/s_1x2.gif",
                           "href":"http://www.ebay.com/itm/MINT-15-Apple-MacBook-Pro-Retina-2-3ghz-i7-8gb-256gb-w-charger-Box-/262420422046?hash=item3d1979dd9e:g:Gl8AAOSw1DtXKhrP"
                        }
                     ],
                     "Vip link":[  
                        {  
                           "text":"MINT 15\" Apple MacBook Pro Retina (2.3ghz i7, 8gb, 256gb) w/charger & Box",
                           "href":"http://www.ebay.com/itm/MINT-15-Apple-MacBook-Pro-Retina-2-3ghz-i7-8gb-256gb-w-charger-Box-/262420422046?hash=item3d1979dd9e:g:Gl8AAOSw1DtXKhrP"
                        }
                     ],
                     "Bold price":[  
                        {  
                           "text":"$1,000.00"
                        },
                        {  
                           "text":"$1,000.00"
                        }
                     ],
                     "Lvformat value":[  
                        {  
                           "text":"Buy It Now"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
   }
}
```

I used http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/ to convert it into java classes. From there I have a group, ebayAPI, image_img, bold_price, vip_link, and data classes.

I'm lost on how I can iterate through the different items in the "group" to pull their price and links.

For instance, when I do this:
        EbayAPI ebayAPI = gson.fromJson(json, EbayAPI.class);
        Vip_link link = gson.fromJson(json, Vip_link.class);

```
    return new String[] {
            "From URL: " + ebayAPI.getUrl(),
            "Vip Link: " + link.getText() 
    }
```

I get the result:

```
From URL: http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_sacat=0&LH_ItemCondition=3000&_nkw=macbook%20pro%2015%202012&rt=nc&LH_BIN=1&_trksid=p2045573.m1684
Vip Link: null
```

Thanks!

---

EbayAPI

```
public class EbayAPI {
    private Result result;

    private String url;

    public Result getResult ()
    {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult (Result result)
    {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public String getUrl ()
    {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl (String url)
    {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [result = "+
                //result +
                ", url = "+url+"]";
    }
}
```

Vip Link

```
public class Vip_link
{
    private String text;

    private String href;

    public String getText ()
    {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText (String text)
    {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getHref ()
    {
        return href;
    }

    public void setHref (String href)
    {
        this.href = href;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [text = "+text+", href = "+href+"]";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the classes you have written. Especially EbayAPI.

Comment: I tried that tool with the JSON you provided and it complains that JSON is not valid

Comment: @gfelisberto yes, sorry I cut it down from it's original form so it wasn't as long. I'll provide the API

Comment: @Jason I added them, thanks